# jcarousel controls stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got a website which has jcarousel as a slider-plugin built-in. I added some placeholder pictures in the backend and everything worked fine for first. The pictures showed the way i wanted and there were 3 little dots in the corner for navigating through the single pictures.

I then went on working on the page for about 2 weeks. At one point i noticed the navigation-dots on the slider disappeard. I have not changed a single line in one of the jcarousel files. Maybe anyone had this before and has a solution?

This is what my html data (which i haven´t edited) says:

```
<div id="jcarousel_box" class="jcarousel-skin-tango" style="width:{$content_data.SET_WIDTH}px; height:{$content_data.SET_HEIGHT}px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" id="jcarousel_slider_id" value="{$content_data.SLIDER_ID}" />
  <div class="jcarousel-control">
      {foreach name=imgPrev item=img_array from=$content_data.IMG_DATA}
      {if $img_array.image_preview || $img_array.image_title_text}
        <a href="#" id="slideImg_{$smarty.foreach.imgPrev.index+1}" style="visibility: hidden;">
        {if $img_array.image_preview}
          <img src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/thumbnails/{$img_array.image_preview}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
        {else}
          {$img_array.image_title_text}
        {/if}
        </a>
      {/if}
      {/foreach}
  </div>
  <div id="jcarousel_image_box" style="width:{$content_data.SET_WIDTH}px; height:{$content_data.SET_HEIGHT}px;">
    <ul style="height:{$content_data.SET_HEIGHT}px;">
        {foreach name=imgBig item=img_array from=$content_data.IMG_DATA}
        <li style="width:{$content_data.SET_WIDTH}px; height:{$content_data.SET_HEIGHT}px;">
          {if $img_array.image_area_array|@sizeof > 0}   
            <img usemap="#map1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
            <map id="map1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" name="map1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}">
              {foreach item=area_array from=$img_array.image_area_array}
                <area id="area1_{$area_array.image_area_id}" shape="{$area_array.image_area_shape}" coords="{$area_array.image_area_coords}" href="{$area_array.image_area_link_url}" alt="{$area_array.image_area_title}" title="{$area_array.image_area_title}" target="{$area_array.image_area_link_target}" />
              {/foreach}
            </map>
          {elseif $img_array.link_url}
            <a href="{$img_array.link_url}" target="{$img_array.link_target}">
              <img class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" title="{$img_array.image_title_text}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
            </a>
          {else}
            <img class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl1_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" title="{$img_array.image_title_text}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
          {/if}
        </li>
        {/foreach}
        {foreach name=imgBig item=img_array from=$content_data.IMG_DATA}
        <li style="width:{$content_data.SET_WIDTH}px;height:{$content_data.SET_HEIGHT}px;">
          {if $img_array.image_area_array|@sizeof > 0}   
            <img usemap="#map2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
            <map id="map2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" name="map2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}">
              {foreach item=area_array from=$img_array.image_area_array}
                <area id="area2_{$area_array.image_area_id}" shape="{$area_array.image_area_shape}" coords="{$area_array.image_area_coords}" href="{$area_array.image_area_link_url}" alt="{$area_array.image_area_title}" title="{$area_array.image_area_title}" target="{$area_array.image_area_link_target}" />
              {/foreach}
            </map>
          {elseif $img_array.link_url}
            <a href="{$img_array.link_url}" target="{$img_array.link_target}">
              <img class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" title="{$img_array.image_title_text}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
            </a>
          {else}
            <img class="slideImgControl" id="slideImgControl2_{$smarty.foreach.imgBig.index+1}" src="{$smarty.const.DIR_WS_IMAGES}slider_images/{$img_array.image_large}" title="{$img_array.image_title_text}" alt="{$img_array.image_alt_text}" />
          {/if}
        </li>
        {/foreach}        
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

and this is what i get as output on my page

```
<div class="jcarousel-control">
                                </div>
```

Comment: what you are having in $img_array? Try to change name=$imgPrev item=$img_array.

Comment: did not work. i am getting an error. i included the rest of the code on the top. This is the only file in my whole workspace where $img_array exists.